# How did I get the popular Question badges with only 718 views?

Tags: discussion, badges, popular-question

I want to know that why, with the top views on a particular question only 718 I still got the `Popular Question` Badge.

Can anyone please tell me that how that is possible? How did I get that badge?

Comment: How did you find that your top viewed question has 718 views?

Comment: @hims056 lack of scrolling or maybe he thought the one with 2K views has 2 views only, missing the different style and "k".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Hmm I too think so.

Comment: that's why i ask this type of silly question,,,,sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you earned this badge on https://stackoverflow.com/badges/26/popular-question?userid=928876  post just click on badge and you will  see list of post on which you got badge

Comment: ok ok i got the answer i was thinking that my top views is 718 but i haven't check 2K views question...thanks..

Answer (score 1):

[You earned the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/26/popular-question?userid=928876) for [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516320/read-csv-file-and-then-insert-its-data-in-sqlserver-database-using-java) Didn't you ask that question which already has 2K+ views. Here is [the list of questions asked by you order by most views](https://stackoverflow.com/users/928876/rahul?tab=questions&sort=views).

Comment: ok ok i got the answer i was thinking that my top views is 718 but i haven't check 2K views question...thanks..